# Put output in a DataGridView with timer

Tags: c#, .net

How can I put the output in a dataGridview with a timer at the click of a button, for  example:

John Brown 18

... after 3 seconds

Carl montgomery 54

... after 3 seconds

Anne Brown 27

stop

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    struct S
    {
    public string name ;
    public string surname;
    public int age;
    }
    S[] vett = new S[100];
    vett[0].name = "John";
    vett[0].surname = "Brown";
    vett[0].age = 18;
    vett[1].name = "Carl";
    vett[1].name = "montgomery";
    vett[1].age = 54;
    vett[2].name = "Anne";
    vett[2].surname = "Brown";
    vett[2].age = 27;
```

```
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;

for (int i = 0; i<vett.Length; i++)
{   
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);  
timer1.Interval = 1000;
timer1.Start(); 
timer1_Tick(vett[i],null);  
}
}

private void timer1_Tick(object o, EventArgs e)
{
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(o.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Please explain the error or functionality (expected output vs current output) that is not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make your struct, timer, and your array class variables instead of method variables.  Also, instead of an array I would use a List.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public struct S
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Surname;
        public int Age;
    }

    private Timer myTimer;
    private List<S> myListOfS;
    private int myListOfSIndex;

    // Constructor
    public MyClass()
    {
        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);  
        myTimer.Interval = 3000; // Your question says 3 seconds

        myListOfS = new List<S>(); 
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myListOfSIndex = 0;
        myListOfS.Clear();

        // Create and add your first S
        S firstS = new S();
        firstS.Name = "John";
        firstS.Surname = "Brown";
        firstS.Age = 18;
        myListOfS.Add(firstS);

        // Create and add your second S
        S secondS = new S();
        firstS.Name = "Carl";
        firstS.Surname = "Montgomery";
        firstS.Age = 54;
        myListOfS.Add(secondS);

        // Create and add your third S
        S thirdS = new S();
        thirdS.Name = "Anne";
        thirdS.Surname = "Brown";
        thirdS.Age = 27;
        myListOfS.Add(thirdS);

        // Start your timer
        myTimer.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(myListOfS[myListOfSIndex]);
        myListOfSIndex++;

        // Stop your timer after you add your 3 objects
        if (myListOfSIndex == 3)
        {
            myTimer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this gives you an idea of what you can do.  I'm sure there are other ways this can be accomplished.